# How can I make a circle with outward curve border in react native?

Tags: react-native

How can I make a circle's outline outwards in bottom,
I tried using

```
borderBottomRightRadius: -50,
borderBottomLeftRadius: -50,
```

but it doesnt work in react native
also I checked similar answers in normal css and html but all the solutions were using psuedo selectors and react native doesnt support this.
I want to achieve the following
Please help me coding this.
[image]